# Select varchar value as column name inside dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my project I am using SQL Server 2008 as back end. I am facing an issue in my  procedure  using dynamic sql. See the sample code for the dynamic sql I am using.

```
      Declare @Sql varchar(Max)     
      set @Sql='Declare @Counter1 int=1; Declare @Counter2 int;
      Declare @PrevMonthAmt decimal(18,2);
      Declare @CurrMonthAmt decimal(18,2);
      Declare @MonthName varchar(100);

      while @Counter1<=(select count(*) from #Tab1)
           begin                               
                set @Counter2 =  (select count(*) from #TabMonths)
                set @MonthName = (select [Month] from #TabMonths where Id=@Start)
                while @Counter2>=1      
                begin
                    select @CurrMonthAmt=@MonthName from #Tab1 where Id=@Counter1
                    select @PrevMonthAmt=@MonthName from #Tab1 where Id=(@Counter1-1)
                    update #Tab1 set @MonthName=(@CurrMonthAmt-@PrevMonthAmt) where Id=@Counter1
                    set @Counter2=@Counter2-1
                end
                set @Counter1= @Counter1+1
            end;
    select *from #Tab1
    ' Exec @Sql
```

Here temporary table #Tab1 contains employee month wise salary details and #TabMonths contains list of all months. Here month columns in both #Tab1 & #TabMonths are not static fields. It will automatically generate from user drop down selection (Start Year and End Year) from the front end UI. If the user selections are start year:2013 & end year:2014, it will create 24 dynamic month columns in both #Tab1 & #TabMonth like Jan, 2013, Feb, 2013 up to Dec, 2014.

I want to update the difference between current month salary and previous month salary in #Tab1. But @MonthName doesn't consider as column name but always treats @MonthName as varchar while selecting from @Tab1. So I don't get the salary of an employee for a particular month. I must want this possible inside the dynamic query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Declare @Counter1 int=1;` shouldn't that be two lines? `DECLARE` on one and `SET` on another?

Comment: Yes, that are in two lines.

Comment: A glance at the code suggests the you do not need to do a nested loop for the results that you want.  I might suggest that you ask another question to see if there is a better way to get the information you want.  You can even set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This is just a sample code that I used for demo purpose. Here month columns in both #Tab1 & #TabMonths are not static fields. It will automatically generate from user  drop down selection (Start Year and End Year) from the front end UI. If the user selections are start year:2013  & end year:2014, it will create 24 dynamic month columns in both #Tab1 & #TabMonth like Jan, 2013, Feb, 2013 up to Dec, 2014.

Comment: you can do 'Declare @Counter1 int=1' in one row.

Comment: Inline variable initialization is possible from SQL server 2008 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these three lines of code. The first and second lines are attempting to assign a varchar to a decimal variable. The third line is attempting to assign a decimal value to a varchar variable.

```
select @CurrMonthAmt=@MonthName from #Tab1 where Id=@Counter1
select @PrevMonthAmt=@MonthName from #Tab1 where Id=(@Counter1-1)
update #Tab1 set @MonthName=(@CurrMonthAmt-@PrevMonthAmt) where Id=@Counter1
```

As a mental exercise, let's replace the variables with values here. Assume that #Tab1 contains data like below, where ... represents the months 4-10, April-October.

```
Id    MonthName
---------------
1    January
2    February
3    March
...    ...
11    November
12    December
```

Focus on this line of code:

```
select @CurrMonthAmt=@MonthName from #Tab1 where Id=@Counter1
```

Substitute 2 for `@Counter1`, and "February" for `@MonthName`, so the code now looks like this:

```
select @CurrMonthAmt="February" from #Tab1 where Id=2
```

You are trying to assign `@CurrMonthAmt` (a decimal representing someone's salary) to the varchar value `"February"` instead of a decimal value, like `5000.00`. Personally, I'd rather be paid `5000.00` instead of `"February"`.

Comment: I know this issue and had specified that in my post. Here the code that I want is select @CurrMonthAmt=[February, 2013] from #Tab1 where Id=2. Here [February, 2013] is a a dynamic column generated in both #Tab1 & #TabMonths. So I will get salary for the month of February, 2013 for an employee.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your table structure. I will review and revise my answer.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869820/tsql-passing-a-varchar-variable-of-column-name-to-sum-function

Comment: Above link just displays how to concatenate a variable into dynamic query. But in my case variable should be inside @sql statement.

Comment: Given that your column name will be variable, does that not make your query dynamic?